# Binding to an IEnumerable<object> dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I've created a custom control, called `SearchableCheckBoxList` (derived from `UserControl`). In this control I have an `ItemsControl`, which contains Items of type `Entry`, as defined here:

```
public class Entry : BindableBase
{
    public Entry(object content)
        : this(content, false)
    { }

    public Entry(object content, bool isChecked)
    {
        Content = content;
        IsChecked = isChecked;
    }

    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._isChecked, value); }
    }

    private object _content;
    public object Content
    {
        get { return _content; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _content, value); }
    }

}
```

In my code behind, I also have a `DependencyProperty` called `ItemsSource` (of type `IEnumerable`) which takes a collection of items (of any type) and converts them to an `Entry` type. That is, for each element in the collection I'm creating a new Entry item and storing that element in the Content property of the Entry item, like this:

```
foreach (var item in ItemsSource)
   itemsControl.Items.Add(new Entry(item));
```

I'm doing this because in my `ItemsControl` I have a checkbox next to each item, and the user can click on one or more checkboxes to select multiple items which will reflect on the IsChecked property of each `Entry` item.

I have another dependency property in my code behind called `SelectedItems`, defined as such:

```
public IEnumerable<object> SelectedItems
{
    get { return (IEnumerable<object>)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(IEnumerable<object>), typeof(SearchableCheckBoxList), 
                                                                    new PropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable<object>)));
```

Every time an item is checked or unchecked in my itemscontrol, I am updating the above DP as such:

```
private void checkBox_CheckChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;

    // Get entry from the content presenter
    var entry = ((Entry)(((ContentPresenter)checkBox.Content).DataContext));

    // Set its checked value based on the checkbox's checked value
    entry.IsChecked = (bool)checkBox.IsChecked;

    // Update selected items collection
    SelectedItems = itemsControl.Items.Cast<Entry>().Where(i => i.IsChecked).Select(i => i.Content).ToList();

}
```

In my main program, I am using this control as such:

```
<controls:SearchableCheckBoxList SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedCities, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding CityCollection, Mode=OneTime}"/>
```

And in my viewmodel `SelectedCities` and `CityCollection` are defined as such:

```
private ObservableCollection<CityModel> _cityCollection;
public ObservableCollection<CityModel> CityCollection
{
    get { return _cityCollection; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _cityCollection, value); }
}

private List<object> _selectedCities = new List<object>();
public List<object> SelectedCities
{
    get { return _selectedCities; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _selectedCities, value); }
}
```

The control looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S3wq.png).

Now, all this works fine and the bindings are updating as expected. The problem I'm having is that for this to work SelectedCities have to be defined as `List<object>`. I want to define SelectedCities as `List<CityModel>`, but if I do this the setter of my property is always called with a value of null. I can't seem to figure out why or what to do.

**EDIT** As requested, here is [SearchableCheckBoxList.xaml](http://pastebin.com/rWc6e6N4) and [SearchableCheckBoxList.cs](http://pastebin.com/HGFaqBRN)

Comment: Can you make `Entry` generic?

Comment: yep. exactly - that way it will stay strongly typed.

Comment: I will do that and let you know what happens

Comment: @DanielA.White I made Entry generic, but in my SearchableCheckBoxList.cs when I'm trying to create an item of type Entry, it's of course asking for the type, which the control is not aware of.

Comment: @kyriacos_k Could you share your entire project somwhere?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot share my entire project, but I can share certain portions. Just tell me what you want to see and I will post it.

Comment: @kyriacos_k your code samples are way too specific. I mean it is hard to reproduce your issue on someone else's machine just from samples you've provided. If you could make a project that illustrates the issue I think you will be helped sooner

Comment: Is there any specific reason for SelectedItems to be of type object and not CityModel?

Comment: Yes so I can reuse it with any type, this is just one case where I'm using it with CityModel

Comment: @netaholic I will post all the code of my SearchableCheckBoxList control in a few minutes

Comment: @kyriacos_k hm Makes sense, can you quickly try to make it CityModel and if that is causing the issue you could look for another way to make it reusable, but if it isn't at least we mark that as not causing the issue.

Comment: @kirotab Code posted on pastebin, can find it on my question edit

Comment: @kyriacos_k Take a look at my answer, please

Comment: I think you make it unnecessary complex. Lets assume you have a ListView and your Items are ListViewItem with a CheckBox and some other things as content. Just bind the IsChecked of the checkbox to IsSelected of the Item and bind the IsSelected of the item to your code behind `<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}` Make SelectedItems a OneWayToSource binding if you need it at all

Answer (score 2):

I believe your issue is that Collections in C# are **not covariant**.
I mean you can't cast `List<Person>` to `List<object>` i.e.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<object> foo = new List<object>();
        List<Person> bar = new List<Person>();

        List<object> some = (List<object>) bar;
    }

    class Person { }
}
```

The program above won't compile. Your program compiles since casting happens indirectly by "`SetProperty`" method.

I think you should either use generics or make a collection of `List<IBaseClass>` instead of "`List<object>`" and make sure all your models are inherited from `IBaseClass`

**UPDATE**

One more way - make your DP property type of an object. It might be confusing for other developers in the team, if there are any. And you will have to manually check types and do casting if you have some logic in your DPs

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var control = new myUserControl();
            myPersons = new List<Person>() { new Person() { Name = "some" } };
            control.SetBinding(myUserControl.MyPropertyProperty, new Binding() { Source = MyPersons });
        }

        private List<Person> myPersons { get; set; }
        public List<Person> MyPersons { get { return myPersons; } set { myPersons = value; } }
    }

    public class Person { public string Name; }

    public class myUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public object MyProperty
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(object), typeof(myUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(0));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I see what you mean, but having a baseclass interface is not an ideal situation, as any model I want to use with this would have to implement it. I'm hoping there's a better solution out there.

Comment: Also using generics is problematic, as you can see in question's comments

Comment: @kyriacos_k To be honest I'm not sure there is a "perfect" solution, and that's why I'm specifying in my code the types of my DependencyProperties explicitly after all the syntax is not a problem with propdp snippet and it is not much that you're reusing

Comment: I will wait and see if someone has a better solution

Comment: @kyriacos_k I've updated my answer with one more way to solve it

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're doing there to be honest and how that is related to SelectedItems

Comment: I mean you can register your SelectedItems as "object" instead of "IEnumerable<object>" and then switch it's type in setter like "case: SelectemItems is IEnumerable<CityMode>"

Comment: And the last option would be to register your DP as object[] and change your binding to SelectedItems = "{Binding  SelectedCities.ToArray()...

Comment: @netaholic I tried using your interface suggestion as a temporary solution. My class is deriving from ISelectableBase and my SelectedItems is of type IEnumerable<ISelectableBase>. The binding is not working however, the value in my property setter is always null

Comment: @kyriacos_k Yes, it won't work without changing SelectedCities to IEnumerable<ISelectableBase>. I'm sorry it's a mistake that I've posted it as a solution. Althought other options should work